# How to re.sub() what i don't want in a string?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this :

```
var1 = {u'data-sport_id': u'basket_us', u'data-event_id':     u'sacramento_kings__golden_state_warriors', u'data-compet_id': u'nba_-_matchs', u'title': u'Basket US - NBA - Matchs - Sacramento Kings // Golden State Warriors - 1 avril 2018 - 4h10', u'data-name': u'sportif.clic.accueil.zone_centrale.details', u'href': u'/event/523450/sports/basket-us/nba-matchs/golden-state-warriors-chez-les-sacramento-kings', u'data-placement': u'bottom', u'data-toggle': u'tooltip', u'class': [u'trow--event', u'tc-track-element-events']}
var2 = {u'data-sport_id': u'rugby_a_xiii', u'data-event_id': u'st_georgeilla_dragons__newcastle_knights', u'data-compet_id': u'nrl', u'title': u'Rugby \xe0 XIII - NRL - St George/Illa Dragons // Newcastle Knights - 1 avril 2018 - 8h10', u'data-name': u'sportif.clic.accueil.zone_centrale.details', u'href': u'/event/521076/sports/rugby-%C3%A0-xiii/nrl/st-georgeilla-dragons-newcastle-knights', u'data-placement': u'bottom', u'data-toggle': u'tooltip', u'class': [u'trow--event', u'tc-track-element-events']}
```

And I want to keep :

```
var1 = basket_us
var2 = rugby_a_xiii
```

I'm trying things this but it doesn't work :

```
re.findall(r"data-sport_id':(.)*'(.)*'", var1)
re.findall(r"data-sport_id':(.)*'(.)*'", var2)
```

But I would like to know, can I do a re.sub() and only keep what I want ?

`(.)*data-sport_id(.)*[WHAT I WANT]'(.)*`

Comment: Why are you using regex here? Can you not just do: `var1 = var1['basket_us']; var2 = var2['rugby_a_xiii']`? Your question really isn't clear.

Comment: I wanted to get the value in the key `data-sport_id`. Anyway Stephen answered, thanks you for your help @Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [dicts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), you can access them like:

#### Code:

```
var1.get('data-sport_id', '')
```

or if you are sure the key will be present like:

```
var1['data-sport_id']
```

#### Test Code:

```
var1 = {u'data-sport_id': u'basket_us',
        u'data-event_id': u'sacramento_kings__golden_state_warriors',
        u'data-compet_id': u'nba_-_matchs',
        u'title': u'Basket US - NBA - Matchs - Sacramento Kings // Golden State Warriors - 1 avril 2018 - 4h10',
        u'data-name': u'sportif.clic.accueil.zone_centrale.details',
        u'href': u'/event/523450/sports/basket-us/nba-matchs/golden-state-warriors-chez-les-sacramento-kings',
        u'data-placement': u'bottom', u'data-toggle': u'tooltip',
        u'class': [u'trow--event', u'tc-track-element-events']}
var2 = {u'data-sport_id': u'rugby_a_xiii',
        u'data-event_id': u'st_georgeilla_dragons__newcastle_knights',
        u'data-compet_id': u'nrl',
        u'title': u'Rugby \xe0 XIII - NRL - St George/Illa Dragons // Newcastle Knights - 1 avril 2018 - 8h10',
        u'data-name': u'sportif.clic.accueil.zone_centrale.details',
        u'href': u'/event/521076/sports/rugby-%C3%A0-xiii/nrl/st-georgeilla-dragons-newcastle-knights',
        u'data-placement': u'bottom', u'data-toggle': u'tooltip',
        u'class': [u'trow--event', u'tc-track-element-events']}


print(var1.get('data-sport_id', ''))
print(var2.get('data-sport_id', ''))
```

#### Results:

```
basket_us
rugby_a_xiii
```

Comment: I didn't know that thanks you, it's very easy in fact.